# wx RibbonBar ButtonBar not showing any icons

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wx.ribbon to create a ribbon bar.
with this code, any time i try to recreate this, the formatting is messed up. I'm not sure how to fix it.

`undo_redo_panel = RB.RibbonPanel(tab, wx.ID_ANY, "Steps", getImage("undo-redo.png"))`

`undo_redo = RB.RibbonButtonBar(undo_redo_panel)`

`undo_redo.AddButton(ID_REDO, "redo", getImage("redo-ico.png"), "redo")`

`undo_redo.AddButton(ID_UNDO, "undo", getImage("undo-ico.png"), "undo")`

I'm not sure where to start

Edit: I forgot to add ribbon.Realise() was the problem.